# ChromeDriver only supports older version error running selenium tests

Tags: c#, asp.net, selenium, google-chrome

I am trying to setup selenium testing on my .net framework 4.7.2 web application. I installed the Selenium.WebDriver - version 3.141.0 and Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver - version 81.0.4044.6900 nuget packages (both the latest stable versions). Although I get the following error when I try to run a Selenium MSTest method:

`Initialization method BookingSystem.Tests.SeleniumChrome.TestInit threw exception. System.InvalidOperationException: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 79 (SessionNotCreated).
    TestCleanup method BookingSystem.Tests.SeleniumChrome.TestClean threw exception. System.NullReferenceException: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object..`

If I am reading this correctly, this error is telling me that this version of ChromeDriver (I have 81.0.4044.6900 nuget package installed) only supports Chrome version 79? My Chrome web browser version is Version 81.0.4044.92, so does this mean I will have to download an older version of Chrome browser?

Answer (score 0):

Your web driver 3.141.0 version is not supporting chrome browser 81. you need to update your webdriver version and pass binary path accordingly. Your current web driver support is valid for 79.XX chrome browser.

To update your webdriver check below link:
[Webdriver Download available here](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/)

Your browser version is automatically updated please download latest chrome driver which will support to your browser version :
you can download  [Latest Chrome driver from here](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads)
You can also update your chrome browser to older version to resolve this issue.

You can find more info from https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/releases

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Web driver 3.141.0 is the newest version so it looks like I can not update it

Comment: Hi Dipak, there is no option to update to 3.141.59 thorugh nuget packages: https://imgur.com/x2gpQI0

Answer (score -1):

update the package Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver instead of Selenium.WebDriver works for me